# Как сделать блок не видимым

Tags: css3, html, css

вообщем задача такая надо убрать отображение блока в шаблоне, как это реализовать при помощи css? JS скрипт загружает шаблон для формы комментариев, под ней находится реклама. Доступа к исходнику js нет. Реклама  помещена в div. Надо ее убрать.

Comment: @maksim16611, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 4):

```
display: none;
```